# How can I integrate $\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2} dx dy$ in the ellipse?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am lookig for  $$\int\int _{D} \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}} dxdy  $$
where $D$ is defined by $D=\{  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}\leq 1 \}$.

please help

Comment: Find the value of double integral sqrt(1-x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2) in the region bounded by the ellipse.

Comment: Let $u=x/a$ and $v=y/b$, then change to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x=ar\cos(t)$ and $br\sin(t)$, where $r \in [0,1]$ and $t \in [0,2\pi)$. We have
$$dxdy = \left \vert \begin{bmatrix}
a\cos(t) & b\sin(t)\\
-ar\sin(t) & br\cos(t)
\end{bmatrix}\right \vert dr dt = abrdrdt$$
Hence, the integral
\begin{align}
I & = {\int\int}_{\text{ellipse}} \sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}}dxdy = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2}abrdrdt\\
& = ab \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 r\sqrt{1-r^2}drdt = 2\pi ab \int_0^1 r \sqrt{1-r^2}dr = \dfrac{2\pi ab}3
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks!! you are very good.